# Php check system requirements multiple if conditions wont work

Tags: php

I am trying to check system requirement using php. But i have one problem.

I have tryed the following code:

```
function CheckEveryThinkOk(){
    $version = phpversion();
    if(($version >= 5.3) && (function_exists('mysqli_connect')) && (in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules())) && (ini_get('short_open_tag')) && (file_exists('../../.htaccess')) && (is_writable('../../core'))){
          return '<div class="continuenextstep">Next Step</div>';
       } else {
          return '<div class="missingSomething">Some requirements seem to be missing.</div>';   
       }
}
```

So problem is. Everything is `TRUE`. But my code return `<div class="missingSomething">Some requirements seem to be missing.</div>` .

It should return `<div class="continuenextstep">Next Step</div>`. What i am missing here any one can tell me ?

Comment: Which of your conditions is true?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter all is ok just `.htaccess` and `core` is not true.

Comment: || means or.  If any of these conditions are true it evaluates as true

Comment: @EatPeanutButter So what i need to do ?

Comment: Evaluate them individually, or if you need them all to be true, use && (and) instead of || (or)

Comment: @EatPeanutButter I have try && (and) but if add .htaccess and core file in the root folder it shows wrong return also. Like `<div class="missingSomething">Some requirements seem to be missing.</div>` But everything is ok.

Comment: Very sure not "everything is ok". I guess `(file_exists('../../.htaccess')) && (is_writable('../../core'))` both conditions fail. Which script is called from the browser? The one in your document root? It includes a script in subfolder/subfolder? Then the working directory is the one of the primary called script.

Comment: Please try `var_dump( file_exists('../../.htaccess'), is_writable('../../core') /* , and any other single condition...*/ )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unclear logic

```
if(($version >= 5.3) || (function_exists('mysqli_connect')) || (in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules())) || (ini_get('short_open_tag')) || (file_exists('../../.htaccess')) || (is_writable('../../core'))){ ....
```

May be

```
function CheckEveryThinkOk(){
    $version = phpversion();

    clearstatcache(true,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/.htaccess');
    clearstatcache(true,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core');

    if(($version >= 5.3) and (function_exists('mysqli_connect')) and (in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules())) and (ini_get('short_open_tag')) and (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/.htaccess')) and (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core'))){
          return '<div class="continuenextstep">Next Step</div>';
       } else {
          return '<div class="missingSomething">Some requirements seem to be missing.</div>';   
       }
}
```

Comment: I have try && (and) but if add `.htaccess` and `core` file in the root folder it shows wrong return also. Like `<div class="missingSomething">Some requirements seem to be missing.</div>` .  But everything is ok.

Comment: (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/.htaccess')) and (is_writable('$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core'))

Comment: Yes i know i saw that. but same problem here.

Comment: Ok! Try clearstatcache(true,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/.htaccess')‌​; clearstatcache(true,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core');

Comment: Why is_writable() ?  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core'  is file?


(file_exists('$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core'))  file_exists check files and dirs

Added changes to the answer